AdGuard Home: DNS IPv4 Rewrite (Discard AAAA) for CNAME Domains
After reading Docs, I still cannot figure out how to:
By default, 2024.aclweb.org CNAMEs to acl-org.github.io.
Lots of domains CNAME to *.github.io, and I want to specify 185.199.111.153 for all domains CNAME to *.github.io. (Due to some reasons, I have to connect via IPv4 only for this domain specially.)
I tried ||github.io^$dnstype=CNAME,dnsrewrite=185.199.111.153 in AdGuard Home Settings, finding that doesn't work.
Is there a method to specify an IP Address for domains and CNAME domains? There are hundreds of domains which CNAME to *.github.io, thus I could not specify them to 185.199.111.153 one by one manually.
Thanks!
